# other options to run android emulator in AMD

Tags: android

are there any other options on ways to test APK in an AMD prcoessor?

I have tried Genymotion however my it seems to eat a lot of CPU power (reaches 90%) i was looking for other options that would not use a lot of cpu power. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check this one:

http://www.leapdroid.com/

I don't know if its AMD

It is a good lightweight emulator

Comment: Yes, Leapdroid works on AMD, and provides the best performance compared to all other emulators.

Comment: does android studio detect Leapdroid as a device like Genymotion?

Comment: Yes, Leapdroid provides the same adb interface as the original android emulator

Answer (score 0):

Although, I use Genymotion at times and don't really find it that slow but if you want you can `Create a new Virtual Device` and while in the `Virtual Device Configuration` window you can select `Other Images` tab and then download the desired `ABI` and then select the ABI as `armeabi` instead of the default `x86` one, as shown below.

---

[image: Virtual Device COnfiguration]

Comment: but which is more efficient in your opinion using a virtual device in Android Studio or using Genymotion

Comment: @Dr.DOOM Genymotion is pretty fast! :)

Comment: i see but is it normal that it is eating too much of my CPU?